# .htaccess directory redirect for version releasing

Tags: .htaccess

I had an idea which is killing me, as I am not very good with htaccess.

I have the url `http://(www./non-www.)example.com/dir/page/file`. 
But I want to redirect this to the directory `root/release/.../dir/page/file`

So

```
root/.htaccess
root/release/1.0/...
root/release/1.5/...
root/release/2.0/...
root/admin/1.0/...
root/admin/1.5/...
root/admin/2.0/...
etc
```

And if they browse to `example.com/admin` you go to `example.com/admin/2.0`.  But I think the tricky bit is that I dont want example.com/`release/version` or example.com/admin/`version` to be seen.

Or I could just have the two versions hosted `release/stable` and `release/beta`.

I hope that makes sense to someone,
Thanks

Comment: Where do you think the rewrite rules are going to get the release numbers from?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the easiest thing would be to make a page like `example.com/admin` that meta-redirects to `example.com/admin/2.0`, then you just do a mod-rewrite to go back to the generic url.  As you increase the versions, just change the meta refresh, because your .htaccess mod-rewrite will have reg-ex that matches to your version numbering system.

example:

First for the `example.com/admin` file, implement a meta-refresh in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='example.com/admin/2.0'">
```

Now do a re-write from the 2.0 (or from any version) back to where you want to go:

```
#first, we need to define the request, in this case, admin/any number
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin/([0-9]*)
# now we need to make it look like it's just the plain admin page
RewriteRule ^$ /admin [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin /admin/([0-9]*) [L]
```

you'll need to fix my reg-ex matches to make it 2 "point" 0

Comment: alternatively, you can do this all without the meta-refresh by specifically re-directing to the version that you want in the directory.